# A counterexample of egregium theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

> How can I prove that $\bar x\circ x^{-1}$ is not an isometry. Where 
>   $$x(u,v)=(u \cos v, u \sin v, \log u)$$ 
>   $$\bar x(u,v)=(u\cos v, u \sin v, v)$$
>   for $0<v<2\pi$ and $u>0$

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem that $x$ is invertible...

Comment: why is not invertible?

Comment: $x(u, v) = x(u ,v + 2\pi)$ so $x$ is not injective.

Comment: The functions $x,\bar x$ are assume to be parametrization of some surfaces. Anyway I will edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\phi=\bar x\circ x^{-1}$.

We can get a result in the following way. Take a $w\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a curve $x(u(t), v(t))$ such that its derivative at zero is $w$. Then $w=\alpha'x_u+\beta'x_v$. Furthermore $d\phi(w)$ is tangent to $\phi(x(u(t),v(t)))=\bar x(u(t), v(t))$ this means that $d\phi(w)=u'\bar x_u+v'\bar x_v$. But calculating we get 
$$<w,w>=u'E+v'G= u'(1+\frac{1}{u^2})+v'u^2$$
and
$$<d\phi(w),d\phi(w)>=u'\bar E+v'\bar G= u'+v'(u^2+1)$$
that are trivial not the same for a lot of points.